# Windows smart screen is displayed when run my installer

Tags: c#, installation, wix

I had created a .msi file using wix Toolset to package my windows c# application.
when users try to run it on their machines it display the following message by windows [image: Windows protect PC]

As you can see it makes the user feel like the App is not safe to be installed.

How should i prevent that from happening , do i have to modify anything in my installer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is sign your MSI so that the publisher is known.  Notice that the message reads "Publisher: Unknown Publisher".  An unknown publisher is just one red flag to Windows that an app might put a PC at risk.

First, you must obtain (purchase) a Microsoft Authenticode code signing certificate from a trusted authority such as [thawte](https://www.thawte.com/code-signing/?tid=a_box_buycs).

Next, sign your MSI using Microsoft's *signtool.exe*:
`signtool.exe sign /n "My certificate name" myinstaller.msi`

If your installer contains external cabs, or if you decide to wrap your installer in a Wix bootstrapper project, check out Wix's [insignia](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/insignia.html) to help you with more advanced signing requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but what do you mean with [ installer contains external cabs].

Comment: I had created a test certificate and signed my .msi file with it and it gave a successful message so i think if i purchased a certificate it will work fine , is not it ??

Comment: When you create an .msi you have the option to bundle everything together into one file (an .msi).  But there's also the option of including some components in separate files called "external cabs" (*.cab).  In that scenario, when you deliver your installer, you deliver the .msi and the .cab file(s).  Since you are delivering multiple files, you must sign all the files (the .msi and also the .cabs).  And your msi must contain the digital signature of the associated cabs. Insignia helps you do that.

Comment: An unknown publisher is just **one** of the flags for Windows SmartScreen.  There may also be other things.  So purchasing a certificate won't guarantee that SmartScreen won't flag it.  But at least the Publisher will be known, and that's significant.

Comment: My MSI is signed, but smartscreen warning is RED (instead of blue as shown above). My name in "Publisher" is shown, but text says "malware" and users are frighten. Why message color is red?